# finding embedded document with condition in both documents mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am developing an program with 2 models, building and floor. The schema are defined as following.

```
var BuildingSchema = new Schema({
    block:{type:String,trim:true},
    project_id:{type:String},
    floors:[{type:Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref:'Floor'}]
})

var FloorSchema = new Schema({
    name:{type:String,trim:true},
    building_id:{type:String,ref:'Building'}
}
```

What I would like to do is to find the floor result with the conditions of floor.name and building.project_id. I have tried this but didn't work

```
floor.find({name:'fname','building_id.project_id':123}).exec()
```

How do I get what I want? Thanks.

Comment: your build_id is a string but you're searching for a number. Did you want "123"?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to make use of [$elemMatch](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/elemMatch/#op._S_elemMatch) to retrieve just the floor. The mongoosejs docs talk about it [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/query.html).

So you might do something like:

```
building.find({"project_id": 123}).where("floors").elemMatch(function(elem){
  elem.match("name", "fname");
});
```

This should only return the floor element that matches `{"name": "fname"}`